# Changing font family for Arabic translation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to change the Font-Family for the Arabic text in the app. I am using i18Next for the translation. The translation is working perfectly but I am trying to add a custom font for just the Arabic language.

`` const {t} = useTranslation({fontNames: [`${GLOBAL_APP_ARABIC_FONT}`]}); ``

Comment: were you able to do it'?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how that works in react but under the assumption that the `lang` attribute changes properly you could do this in CSS:

```
html {
    font-family: your-latin-font
}
html[lang*=ar] {
    font-family: your-arabic-font
}
```

Comment: Yes I was hoping for some help in adding it as a global font when Arabic is chosen and not in the StyledComponents/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set a global font-family we have a similar thing in our app we just created a custom component for text so that we don't have to set font-family in every Text component.

I am sharing coding for our component you can tweak it to use in JS and use it instead of Text if you like this solution.

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';
import { useStores } from '../stores/rootStore';

type OwnProps = {
  RTLAlign?: boolean;
};

export const AppText = observer((props: TextProps & OwnProps) => {
  const { settingsStore } = useStores();
  const { style, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <Text
      allowFontScaling={false}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
      {...rest}
      style={[
        {
          fontFamily: settingsStore.font // Set condition for font family based on language
        },
        style
      ]}
    />
  );
});
```